# Find anagrams in Groovy

Tags: groovy, functional-programming, anagram

The task I'm writing a script for is finding anagrams and then sorting words in the descending order of the number of anagrams found (or alphabetically when the number for two words is the same). My script looks like this:

```
static getCharactersCount(String word) {
    def res = [:]
    word.each { res.merge(it, 1, Integer::sum) }
    return res
}

//def data = new URL('http://wiki.puzzlers.org/pub/wordlists/unixdict.txt').getText().split("\n").collect { it.trim() }
data = ["hello",  "abc", "heoll", "def", "olehl"]

def res = data
        .groupBy { getCharactersCount(it) }
        .collect { it.value }

def anagramMap = [:]
res.each {
    anagrams ->
        anagrams.each {
            anagramMap[it] = anagrams.toSet().minus(it)
        }
}

anagramMap
        .findAll { it.value.size() > 0 }
        .sort { a1, a2 ->
            a1.value.size() == a2.value.size() ? a1.key.compareTo(a2.key) : a2.value.size() - a1.value.size()
        }
        .each { println("$it.key: ${it.value.join(" ")}") }
```

The script works correctly, however I wonder whether the `anagramMap` variable is necessary. Is it possible to integrate the logic that fills the `anagramMap` with keys and values as operations on the `data` object?

I tried integrating the logic but failed:

```
data
        .groupBy { getCharactersCount(it) }
        .collect { it.value }
        .each {map -> map.value.each {println("$it, ${map.value.toSet().minus(it)}")}}
```

EDIT:

The result should be printed out to the console. One line stores one word and its anagrams. Words without anagrams are ignored:

```
hello: olehl heoll
heoll: olehl hello
olehl: hello heoll
```

Comment: provide the desired output

Comment: @injecteer, I edited the question so that it reflects the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

I would put it like so:

```
def data = ["hello",  "abc", "heoll", "def", "olehl"]

def freqs = data.groupBy{ it.chars().sum() }*.value.inject( [:] ){ res, curr ->
  int size = curr.size()
  curr.each{ res[ it ] = size }
  res
}

def sorted = data.sort{ a, b -> freqs[ b ] <=> freqs[ a ] ?: a <=> b }

assert sorted.toString() == '[hello, heoll, olehl, abc, def]'
```

Comment: the result of original code bit different, but i like the idea with inject

Answer (score 1):

```
def data = ["hello",  "abc", "heoll", "def", "olehl", "fed"]

data
   .groupBy { word-> word.iterator().countBy{it} }  // group words by map [char:count]
   .collectMany{ chars,anagrams->
       // collect groups of words(anagrams) as pairs [word, anagrams-word]
       anagrams.collect{ [it, anagrams.toSet().minus(it)] } 
   }
   .collectEntries()  // convert collection of pairs to map
   .findAll { it.value.size() > 0 }
   .sort { a1, a2 -> a2.value.size() <=> a1.value.size() ?: a1.key <=> a2.key }
   .each { println("$it.key: ${it.value.join(' ')}") }
```

result:

```
hello: olehl heoll
heoll: olehl hello
olehl: hello heoll
def: fed
fed: def
```